# DotNetNuke throws itself into Quirks mode without changing settings

Tags: dotnetnuke, doctype

We've never experienced this before with DNN but sites which have been running for a long time is throwing itself into Quirks mode because the FallBack Skin Doctype has changed to HTML4 (Legacy).

The only thing I am doing differently now is developing directly onto the ASCX file rather than parsing the skin like I have done in the past. I am not going anywhere near the Host Settings during this process.

Any ideas please?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If the skin doesn't specify the DocType then DNN looks at the Host Setting for it. So, you can either change it in the host setting (preferred) or specify it in the skin. Using ASCX for defining the skin rather than HTML shouldn't make any difference.

To specify the doctype for the skin, you have two options:
1.) Create a file named, "Your Skin Name".doctype.xml.  e.g. myskin.doctype.xml

In the file, put the following:

```
<SkinDocType>
<![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">]]>
</SkinDocType>
```

2.) Add the following at the top of your skin

```
<script runat="server">
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim skinDocType as Control = Me.Page.FindControl("skinDocType")
       If Not skinDocType is Nothing
           CType(skinDocType, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal).Text="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">"
       End If
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Oddly enough we have 3 other sites for the exact same client and this is not happening to any of the other sites. What is different in the other sites though is that their XML DocTypes are set to strict as opposed to Transitional. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I've built over 100 DNN sites over the years and haven't seen anything like what you're describing. So, I don't think it's DNN, but can't really guess at what it might be. If you specify the DocType and it's not taking, then that narrows the problem a lot. If the doctype is being rendered properly (do a view source on the page), and IE is still switching to quirks mode, that's a very different but narrower problem.